# React - can't get this.refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React 0.14.7. Inside my render I am trying to access ref "progressBar", but without success ( I get 'undefined' in the console ).
what am I doing wrong?

```
let element = this.refs.progressBar;
console.log( element );
element.style.transform = 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)'; 



 return(
    ...
       <div className="bar-progress">
           <div className="bar-progress-fill" ref="progressBar"></div>
       </div>
       ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because `refs` are not available in `initial render` as you are trying to access it even before its created. You should be doing it in the `componentDidMount` function, if you only want to do it once or add it with a condition in `componentDidUpdate` as React Docs warns you to not use it in render.

NOTE: React docs suggesst you on using the callback approach for refs over string approach 
See this **[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)**

So modify your code like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
     count: 0
  }
 componentDidMount(){
     var deg = 30;
     let element = this.progressBar;
console.log( element );
element.style.transform = 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)';
     this.setState({count: 1}); 
 }
 render() {
  

 console.log(this)

 return(
       <div className="bar-progress">
           <div className="bar-progress-fill" ref={(pb) =>this.progressBar=pb}></div>
       </div>
      );

 }
 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I found this doc. https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html. https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions

Comment: @Ved As it says, it's a caution, doesn't mean it is not available. The OP used it without a check in the render and it resulted in an error. However I truly support that we should not use it within render

Comment: You are correct. Jut tested it. It is available inside render as well. but should be avoided .

Comment: Exactly, An I agree that we shouldn't use it in render :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not access `refs` inside `render()`. `Refs` is accessable only inside react lifecycle methods.

In your case you should use componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
let element = this.refs.progressBar;
console.log( element );
element.style.transform = 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)'; 

}
```

**EDIT 1**: `ref` is accessable inside `render()`, but `refs` are not available in initial render. Please refer the link for more details.
 Example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81735/)

DOC: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions

Comment: I don't think that is the case ved, See my snippet. You have the ref available inside render but its initialised only after the first render

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri do you get any value when : let element = this.refs.progressBar;
console.log( element );

Comment: As I said, not at the initial render but everytime thereafter. If you run my snippet you will see the output that confirms it. Also since it's preferred to use ref callback, instead of ref you will see progressBar being available in the second run

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I will take a look. Thanks for pointing. I still have a doubt on using refs inside render.